# Unable to register java class with JSF 2.0 annotations

Tags: jsf, annotations

In my JSF project, I'm trying to register java classes with JSF 2.0 annotations instead of registering the classes in the faces-config.xml file.

When I register the classes in the faces-config.xml file everything works.  However, when I register the classes using annotations, I get the following error in the server log:

```
WARNING: ApplicationDispatcher[/de.vogella.jsf.card2] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'cardController' resolved to null
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:131)
...

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'cardController' resolved to null
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:131)
...
```

I'm new to these technologies so any help is greatly appreciated!

The following is my set up when things don't work.

**CardController.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CardController {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{card}")
    private Card card;

    ...


    public Card getCard() {
        return card;
    }

    public void setCard(Card card) {
        this.card = card;
    }
}
```

**Card.java**

```
@ManagedBean
public class Card {
    ...
}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

I'm using JSF 2.0 with Mojarra 2.0.3-FCS and I'm running everything on Glassfish 3.1 integrated with Eclipse Helios and using JDK1.6.0_26.

FYI, the tutorial this project is derived from is http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaServerFaces/article.html#installation by Lars Vogel.

Comment: I'm not sure. Everything posted as far seems to look fine. But I do see that you're reading a JSF 1.2 + Tomcat tutorial and are using JSP. JSP is been succeeded by Facelets. Consider reading a real JSF 2.0 + Facelets + Glassfish tutorial. [Here's one](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html).

Comment: Good point.  Actually, your tutorial was the first one I worked on.  Thanks for writing it by the way! It was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If  "server modules without publishing" option is selected then  `@ManagedBean` does not work.

Double click on Tomcat and then unselect this option and restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation, use name attribute with @ManagedBean annotation.

```
@ManagedBean(name="cardController")
```